# Como diferenciar uma url digitada pelo usuário e a invocada pelo código html

Tags: linux, redes, http-headers, firewall

Preciso montar um relatório analítico para um cliente sobre quais URLs cada usuário da rede acessou. Porém, os relatórios que tenho observado, mostram milhares de registros que não servem para essa finalidade. A citar as apis, jpgs, js e css que os códigos html chamam quando uma página é carregada. Por tanto, dentro de um firewall em servidor linux, como posso diferenciar as URLs que os usuários acessaram e as que os códigos em html invocaram (também os demais tráfegos que passam por ele).
Quais informações eu deveria buscar para saber o que o usuário realmente digitou?

Comment: Pode rastrear só os ficheiros que têm `.php` ou `.html`

Answer (score 0):

Existem firewalls com módulos de proxy que já fazem esse rastreio/bloqueio pra você e que até emite relatório também, mas pra fazer na mão o certo seria buscar pelo método GET do HTTP e que contenha os formatos php, html, asp, aspx entre outros, isso que realmente é o que o usuário visivelmente quis acessar.